# Como iniciar um textbox com valor 0 (zero)?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Tenho um formulário criado com Windows Forms, e nesse formulário tenho `textbox` que vai receber números.

Como faço para que este `textbox`, ao inicializar, já esteja preenchido com valor 0, ou seja quando eu abrir o formulário, o `textbox` já carregar com valor 0, mas que seja possível eu alterar para um outro valor posteriormente?

Comment: Colocando o valor 0 nele. Como fazer isto depende do seu código que não foi colocado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No evento

```
Form_Load()
```

Você coloca:

```
seuTextbox.Text = "0";
```

Como mencionado no comentário do Renan Silveira você pode fazer assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não estou conseguindo responder, mas essa resposta esta certa.
Ou vc vai nas propriedades do Campo e no "Text" vc coloca 0 para abrir já com valor.
Tem caso vc queria receber só numero usa o campo "MaskedTextBox, e nas propriedades coloca só numero e um valor iniciar funciona melhor para vc limitar só valor numerico

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho aqui.